# Flask blueprints with gevent working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask, gevent, flask-mail

I am trying to send emails asynchronously with in Flask with gevent via flask-mail. I am getting "working outside of application context". I am aware of with app.app_context() but I cannot get it to work with my setup.

My application is created with an application factory like this:

**myproject/run_dev.py**

```
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
from my_project.app import create_app
from my_project.config import DevConfig

app = create_app(DevConfig)
http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

**myproject/myproject/app.py**

```
def create_app(config=None, app_name=None, blueprints=None):
    app = Flask(app_name)
    configure_app(app, config)
    <other stuff>
    return app
```

And the code that I use to send emails:

**myproject/myproject/mymodule/views.py**

```
@mymodule.route('/some/path/')
def do_something():
    do_stuff(something)
```

**myproject/myproject/mymodule/utils.py**

```
def do_stuff(something):
    send_email(msg)

@async
def send_async_email(msg):
    mail.send(msg)

def send_mail(request_id, recipients, email_type, env=None, pool=None):
    msg = Message(
        sender=sender,
        recipients=recipients,
        subject=subject,
        body=body)
    send_async_email(msg)
```

**myproject/myproject/decorators.py**

```
def async(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = Greenlet.spawn(f, *args, **kwargs)
        gevent.joinall([t])
    return wrapper
```

I have tried to add:

```
from myproject.app import create_app
app = create_app()
with app.app_context():
    mail.send(msg)
```

to send_async_email() but then I get

> ImportError: cannot import name create_app

Comment: When you tried adding the app context to send_async_email, was the import inside the function definition? Because the ImportError looks like a circular dependency?

Comment: No it wasn't. It was at the top with the rest of the imports. I just tried to put it inside the function and indeed it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, glad it works. Added it as an answer for future visitors with a similar issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For historical purposes: putting the `from myproject.app import create_app` inside the `send_async_email` instead of at the top of with the rest of the imports solved the ImportError, because it caused a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your async function within your view and use the `@copy_current_request_context decorator`, so that it can have access to the current request (and app) context.

For details: [documentation of `flask.copy_current_request_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.copy_current_request_context).